# Remove characters from string in column name just for a few columns

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory, multiple-columns, rename

Hi I have a dataframe with 75 characters in the columns name that I don't need to make a chart with matplot so I was trying to use this line:

```
dfr = dfr.iloc[:,1:11].rename(columns=lambda x: x[75:], inplace=True)
```

But when I print it gives me none, I just need to remove this from the first 10 columns the rest are ok, but I'm not sure what is wrong, help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to slice the dataframe and rename the sliced dataset columns and re-assigning to the original dataset which has a different shape.

Try renaming using dict

```
new_names = dfr.iloc[:,0:10].rename(columns=lambda x: x[75:]).columns #first 10 columns
dfr.rename(columns=dict(zip(dfr.columns,new_names)),inplace=True)
```

Comment: Hi I was trying to do the same for other part in the df but it didn't work look:

new_names2 = dfr.iloc[:,19:29].rename(columns=lambda x: x[38:]).columns #first 10 columns
dfr.rename(columns=dict(zip(dfr.columns,new_names2)),inplace=True) I want to erase the 38 characters from the columns 19-29 and replace in the same space